# Getting a substring of a delimited string

Tags: c#, strings

I have some underscore-delimited strings like `abc_def_ghi`.  I would like to get a substring out of the string made of one or more delimited substrings, so that if I call:

```
getUnderscoreSubstring("abc_def_ghi",2)
```

then I get:

```
abc_def
```

This is the C# code I'm using:

```
public string getUnderscoreSubstring(string fullStr,int substringCount)
{
    string[] splitArray = fullStr.Split('_');
    if (substringCount>splitArray.Count())
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        string output = "";
        for(int c=0;c<substringCount;c++)
        {
            output += splitArray[c];
            if (c<substringCount-1)
            {
                output += "_";
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to rewrite this, possibly using extension methods.

Comment: Please clarify your motivation. What do you want to be the result of `getUnderscoreSubstring("__abc_def_ghi", 2)`, and why?

Comment: I don't have any values like that in the data set; they would be excluded from these function calls by prior validation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely simplify this.

```
public string GetSubstring(string input, int count, char delimiter)
{
    return string.Join(delimiter.ToString(), 
                       input.Split(delimiter).Take(count));
}
```

Calling it is as easy as `GetSubstring(input, 2, '_')`

What does it do?

- Split the input string by the delimiter
- Take the amount of substrings you want
- Glue the selected substrings together with your delimiter

Very short and sexy!

This doesn't take the `substringCount > splitArray.Count()` in account but you can easily add that yourself: just split up the oneliner and add the appropriate check.

---

Now, some comments about your code:

- Use `.Length` instead of `.Count()` when possible: the former will always be an O(1) operation, the latter sometimes an O(n). It won't make a difference here since an array implements `ICollection<T>` (and will use this optimization) but it's a good practice to observe.
- Returning `null` is typically avoided for good reasons, consider an empty string or exception instead (don't go for the exception in this case).
- I prefer to explicitly use `string.Empty` rather than an empty string to avoid confusion.
- Write your variable names in full -- nobody is helped by abbreviating them.
- Use a StringBuilder to concatenate in a loop to avoid unnecessary string object creating.
- Leave some space in your code, it will read more fluently.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want to find the `substringCount`th occurrence of '_' in the string, and return all the characters before that.

Basing on the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11363213/1108056

```
private int IndexOfNth(string str, char c, int n)
{
    int index = -1;
    while (n-- > 0)
    {
        index = str.IndexOf(c, index + 1);
        if (index == -1) break;
    }
    return index;
}

public string GetSubstring(string input, int count, char delimiter)
{
    return input.Substring(0,IndexOfNth(input, delimiter, count));
}
```